# How to print special characters in android

Tags: android

Here is my webservice response..

> Testperson-se,Approved,Stårgatan 1,12345,Ankeborg,SE

Now in this string at Stårgatan one special character a with dot is there when i print this response it give me question mark string like ..

> Testperson-se,Approved,St?rgatan 1,12345,Ankeborg,SE

I use following code.

```
try {
            URL url = new URL(
                    "http://www.ecodor.se/administrator/components/com_ivmstore/ivmwebservices/getaddress.php?pNumber=410321-9202"
                            );// 

            InputSource is = new InputSource(url.openStream());

            StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer();

            res.append(convertStreamToString(is.getByteStream()));

            line = res.toString();

            Log.i("==> responce", line);

            //

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

public String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    /*
     * To convert the InputStream to String we use the
     * BufferedReader.readLine() method. We iterate until the BufferedReader
     * return null which means there's no more data to read. Each line will
     * appended to a StringBuilder and returned as String.
     */
    if (is != null) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

How to print this special character?

Comment: It seems that you read the data correctly (assuming the input really is UTF-8 encoded). Probably it is because the terminal cannot display UTF-8? (Are you using Windows cmd?)

Comment: Look at this link - http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=507 . In this link Check Comment 4 by p...@hotmail.com, Aug 25, 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by using following.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is, "ISO-8859-1"));
```

Thanks to all which give me idea.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use encoding returned by [InputSource#getEncoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html#getEncoding%28%29)

> Get the character encoding for a byte stream or URI. This value will be ignored when the application provides a character stream.